# Intellisense in template string with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just wondering if there exists an option to add intellsense with template strings. Currently if i have a simple code block

```
let foo = fooValue === 'foo one' : 'foo two';
this.fooComponent(`this is a message for ${foo}`);
```

I do not get intellsense on typing `${` which i would expect `foo` to be picked up as i type `f` which it does in normal code outside of strings.

Comment: I doubt intellisense is smart enough to pick up string interpolation arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCodes does fully support intellisense in JavaScript and TypeScript strings but it does not trigger automatically. You have to use the `editor.action.triggerSuggest` command which is bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> by default:

[image]